# 3 radio btns - 2 to show - 1 to hide input

Tags: jquery, radio-button

i have multiple div.box on site like this one down here:

```
<div class="box">
<span><input type="radio" class="srcshow" name="addpost_image_wrapper_source">show</span>
<span><input type="radio" class="srcshow" name="addpost_image_wrapper_source">show</span>
<span><input type="radio" class="srchide" name="addpost_image_wrapper_source">hide</span>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

and i have a simple script:

```
$('div.box input:radio.srchide').change(function(){
            $('div.box input:text').fadeOut('fast');
});
$('div.box input:radio.srcshow').change(function(){
            $('div.box input:text').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Well, it's working (almost) but first of all i think it could be better writed (because i suck at writing scripts) and second of all when i click hide button it's hiding all text inputs not the only one under radio's that i clicked.

Could you guys help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.siblings()` and `.parent()` as shown :-

```
$('div.box input:radio.srchide').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('input:text').fadeOut('fast');
});
$('div.box input:radio.srcshow').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings('input:text').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qncfp86e/).

Comment: Thank you good man for fast answer, it's hiding in specific div now - that's ok but it's not showing up when i click srcshow (dont know why)

Comment: @n0xx..i have made a little change in answer..plz try updated answer and visit fiddle link..

Comment: It's working like a charm!
Thank you for your help Kartikeya, +1 magic point for your help.
Have a good day.